# Get values in table from a custom attribute name and value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery in a [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) userscript to traverse and get the values of each table td element below. I would like to do it by the `ng-if="links.hasAvailableWithdrawal"` and `ng-if="links.hasMarginPurchasingPower"` elements.

```
<table class="table-horizontal col-xs-12 ng-scope">
   <tbody>
       <tr ng-if="links.hasAvailableWithdrawal">
           <th>Available for Withdrawal</th>
               <td class="tertiary text-right ng-scope ng-binding" ng-if="!account.unAvailable">
                   $14,588.07
               </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-if="links.hasMarginPurchasingPower">
           <th>Purchasing Power</th>
               <td class="tertiary text-right ng-scope ng-binding" ng-if="!account.unAvailable">
                  $54,286.98
               </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to accomplish something like this to get the dollar values:

```
var available_withdrawal = $('tr[ng-if="links.hasAvailableWithdrawal"] td:last-child').html();
var margin = $('tr[ng-if="links.hasMarginPurchasingPower"] td:last-child').html();
```

I can't seem to get it to work. I am trying to avoid a foreach statement. Would rather get the values from their custom `ng-if` attribute names.

Desired Results:

available_withdrawal = "$14,588.07"

margin = "$54,286.98"

Comment: Doesn't make sense using jQuery to do this in an angular app. Aren't those values available in your scope model?

Comment: @charlietfl true. I am using tampermonkey on top of a website that is using angular to get the values and then post them back to my server. So while the website script is using angular I am trying to use jquery. Unless you see an easier solution

Comment: And what is not working? In [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/pYjzPM?editors=1011) I only added `.trim()` to your code...

Comment: Ah ok. Was no mention of this being a userscript

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thanks for the codepen. What if the raw html is something like this: <tr ng-if="links.hasAvailableWithdrawal &amp;&amp; !links.hasBuyingPower &amp;&amp; !links.hasLocPledgedFlag">

Comment: Look for [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) a bit more... Focus on the operators like `^=` and `*=`. Sorry can't help more here.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thank you! This worked `^=`